# How do I manually add an email source to a Google Calendar event?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

It's possible to create a Google Calendar event by [clicking a date or time in a Gmail](https://www.lifewire.com/create-a-google-calendar-event-from-a-message-in-gmail-1172093) message. The newly created event will then have a link back to the original email.

[image]

Is it possible to add an email source to a Google Calendar event that's already been created? Or alternatively, can a calendar event be created from an email which doesn't include a date or time?